# I only exist for a reason

Tags: riddle, rhyme

```
Older than history, as young as today, 
I was here before you, and I'm here to stay.

My fathers were high, my mother had might
I'm beloved of nobles, but never by right. 

Conceived in the garden, I walk in all weather
then disappear all black in a flutter of feather. 

I dally with dahlias, I rib with the rose,
I enter the forest surrounded by does. 

I'm awarded degrees, yet not educated, 
they judge me as worst among the related. 

You always see me but hope we don't meet
I never respect you, but if you scream, I will bleed. 

I'll arrive in a glass, or I'll arrive in a wave
and then my sad ballads will emerge from the cave.
```

Who am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little grim, but I believe the answer is:

> **Murder**

*Older than history, as young as today, / I was here before you, and I'm here to stay.*

> People have been killing each other forever, and will likely continue doing so for a while yet.

*My fathers were high, my mother had might*

> Murders are committed by the high and mighty.

*I'm beloved of nobles, but never by right.*

> Nothing nobility likes more than a good old fashioned bit of murder (but that doesn't make it right).

*Conceived in the garden, I walk in all weather / then disappear all black in a flutter of feather.*

> A murder of crows.

*I dally with dahlias, I rib with the rose,*

> References to [The Black Dahlia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Dahlia) murder, and to serial killer [Rose West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosemary_West).

*I enter the forest surrounded by does.*

> Murderers often dump their victims (John/Jane Does) in forests.

*I'm awarded degrees, yet not educated, / they judge me as worst among the related.*

> Generally considered the worst crime, and is graded in degrees (first/second degree murder, etc).

*You always see me but hope we don't meet*

> Seen on the news/movies/etc.

*I never respect you, but if you scream, I will bleed.*

> From the idiom, to scream bloody murder.

*I'll arrive in a glass, or I'll arrive in a wave / and then my sad ballads will emerge from the cave.*

> Reference to musician [Nick Cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Cave_and_the_Bad_Seeds), who has an album called Murder Ballads.

Comment: Impressive! This is the right answer, and you got almost clues in the intended way. For those interested, here my original intention: "I exist for a reason" is a way of saying that if you don't intend to kill someone, it's manslaughter, not murder. "My fathers are high" is a reference to the assasins, whose name is derived from "hashish". "My mother" is Lucrecia Borgia, the first(?) woman famous specifically for being a murderer. "Conceived in the garden" is a somewhat stretched allusion to the story of Cain and Abel being rooted in the garden of Eden story. The fourth stanza lists (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) victims, so the rose is Rosa Luxemburg, a political activist who was murdered in the 20th century just like the black dahlia. "Worst among the related" was a gardenpath sentence meaning that murdering your close relatives is seen as even more horrible than murdering strangers. "I'll arrive in a glass" is about the classic poisoned drink, "I'll arrive in a wave" is connected to a crime wave. Having cleared up that, I'd like to ask you: which clue made you first come up with the solution?

Comment: @rumtscho - the word "dahlias" was my way in. Figured if it wasn't specifically important, you would have gone with something like daisies. Was aware of the murder, and a band of the same name, which ironically led me to Nick Cave, by way of music. But, then confirmation from black feathers and degrees (which I already assumed had some non-educational interpretation like temperature, angle or severity) got me to the intended solution.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the answer is:

> Water, rain, storm, weather related... they all seem to kinda fit

Explanation:

Older than history, as young as today, 
I was here before you, and I'm here to stay.

> The atoms have been here for a long time, and so has the water in one form or another.

My fathers were high, my mother had might
I'm beloved of nobles, but never by right.

> Father as in God or maybe Zeus if its about a storm.  Could also be a cloud.  Mother is Mother Earth.
>  Jesus turned water into wine? Not sure about right...

Conceived in the garden, I walk in all weather
then disappear all black in a flutter of feather.

> Moisture in "gardens" (or forests) often condenses and brings rain or storms.
>  Storm clouds are dark.

I enter the forest surrounded by does.

> the forest again with the rain idea.

I'm awarded degrees, yet not educated, 
they judge me as worst among the related.

> Degrees -- > Weather  and judging as worst among the related, a storm cloud is "worse" than regular fluffy clouds.

I'll arrive in a glass, or I'll arrive in a wave

> Water

Another guess I've got to fit into a few parts is:

> money

Comment: I like the guess. It's not the one I intended, but it's not too bad a fit.